# Choose a Remote procedure call c++ library

Tags: c++, protocols, rpc, asn.1

I have to rewrite an old "proprietary" client-server protocol in a standard way.
I'm looking for an abstract notation to define the protocol and a cross-platform implementation library.

I tempted to use ASN.1 because its a well defined standard, but it seems to lack in free implementations, though there are some very good commercial tools like Oss Nokava and Objective-System

For now I found the free [NCBI C++ Toolk](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7197/) which seems interesting because it has a ASN.1 "class generator" and its implementation.

The others solutions I found are:

- ICE
- Thrift
- MessagePack
- Protocol Buffers

[Here](http://distributedsenses.blogspot.it/2012/03/there-are-various-flavors-of-rpc.html) I found a comparison table.
These have pro and cons and so I'm here to ask if someone have had experiences and could give me some suggestions.

Regards, Daniele.

Comment: What sort of performance are you expecting, and what sort of resource restrictions are you operating under? Using a text protocol and a managed language to parse it is a good way to avoid the huge number of buffer overflow vulnerabilities that C and C++ ASN1 implementations have suffered from over the years.

Comment: Consider [Boost's serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) as well. But if you want a ready made framework, there is [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Rook: I have to build a concurrent server which handles some hardware and the performance is not a critical aspect since the workload on the "protocol side" is very low (It has to serve a max of 10-30 clients), also I think to not have big resource restrictions. I agree with you about text protocol (the actual one is a text based protocol) and I also looking for a XML-RPC, how do you think about? Instead for the language, my side is in C++ but the "client side" could be in amy language.
Thanks user315052 since I use boost too, I'm looking to serialization!

Comment: http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/ is another good option for non performance critical application, it would nicely work together with JAX-WS.

Comment: It is the server side implementation which most needs to worry about security problems, I'd say! I'd be very inclined to write this in Java or Python or C# or whatever is the managed language of your choice. XML-RPC is fine; it is certainly much less bloated than SOAP, for example... but then, you can get SOAP handling almost for free in any number of web application frameworks, as it is rather more common.

Comment: I never consider SOAP before because I thought it was "too much" for my purpose but, instead, it could be another solution (and now the choice is more difficult :-) ) . gsoap2 seems to be nice since it handle all the process (serialize->send // receive->deserialize). What I'm looking for is exactly an "all-in-one" solution to handle the RPC.

Answer (score 1):

Your "temptation" to use ASN.1 is a good one.  There are several free ASN.1 Tools in addition to the commercial ones you mentioned.  The benefit of technical support that comes with a commercial tool is usually well worth the cost.  However, an excellent list of available ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial) is available at the following URL: http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm

Note that the ASN.1 Tool from OSS Nokalva includes a socket memory manager and client/server examples that may be helpful in your development.  You can download a free trial from http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-download.html